# Let person login to google docs automatically

Tags: web-applications, google-code, google-docs-api, google-docs

I write a web application that allow person1 create a document on google docs and share it to person2.

A problem: When person2 click on the link of shared document, google alway redirect to login page.

I can store Person2 UserName and Password in database, but there are any way to let person2 login to google docs automatically?

Comment: How do you authenticate person2?  How they login so that you know that they have permission?

Comment: I can collect person2 Username and password. How can i pass that login info to google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking is exactly supported by Google's free services.  The closest thing is their [Single-Sign-On](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html), but this seems to only be available for Google Apps for Business/Education.

They have other options which are not exactly what you're asking.  For example you could use the [Google OpenId](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html) to log into you're web site.  Using this approach a user will already be logged into Google while browsing your site, and therefore won't be bothered by a Google login page when they navigate to a Google spreadsheet.

You can also use username/password to access the [Google Spreadsheet API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#Authenticating), but this just gets you access to the data, not the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple permissions problem, you have set the document to be private or only granted explicit permission to select people.  Try changing the visibility to "public on the web" or "anyone with the link" so no sign in is required.

http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=183965&hl=en_GB

Comment: Thank for your answer. But i have some documents and i don't want to public to everyone.